# What report will be produced with these SAS codes

Tags: sas

Given the SAS data set WORK.ONE:

```
  X  Y   Z 
  -  -  -- 
  1  A  27 
  1  A  33 
  1  B  45 
  2  A  52 
  2  B  69 
  3  B  70 
  4  A  82 
  4  C  91
```

The following SAS program is submitted:

```
  data WORK.TWO;
     set WORK.ONE; 
     by X Y;
     if First.Y;
  run;
  proc print data=WORK.TWO noobs;
  run;
```

I don't understand first. and last. after a by statement with two variables. 
If it's like 
 by Y;
 if First.Y; 
I know what's going on in the data step. 
But now, it seems a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TWO` will contain the records from `ONE` that are the first record for each new value of `Y`, or each new value of `X` (if that is any additional records).  So, the first record for `1 A`, `1 B`, `2 A`, `2 B`, `3 B`,  `4 A`, and `4 C`.

Basically, in a compound `BY` statement, each time a variable's value changes, that variable *and every variable to the right in the by statement* sets `first.` to 1 (true).

Comment: I just figure it out. hah. Thanks anyway.